# Plugin.FirebasePushNotification installation error in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

While installing Plugin.FirebasePushNotification getting error-

Could not install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.0'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.

after updating Android API 7.0 this installation works well(when create a new project)

BUT i already have a project with compile version Android 6.0.
While installing this plugin on this project then it shows same error.

So how to solve this installation issue on my previous project?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to set your `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` to Android 8.0 or greater.**

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/ version 60.1142.0 only includes a `MonoAndroid80` folder which means it requires APIs from Xamarin.Android 8.0 at a minimum to compile against.

If you want to figure this out yourself, do the following:

1. Download https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer
2. Download the NuGet via [Manual Download](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/60.1142.0)
3. Open the `.nupkg`
4. Expand the `lib` folder to see the respective target frameworks